# Windows 10 powershell ise compress-archive files at root .in .zip

Tags: windows, powershell, compression, php-ziparchive

With Windows(10) powerShell ise,
Is it possible to zip the content of a folder, like it does with command 'Compress-Archive', but not encapsuled it in a root folder on th zip ?

(Get the files at root in the zip)

eg: - myFolder { index.html, mycss.css, myConn.php}

**used command**: `-DestinationPath C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\myZip.zip -Path C:\wamp64\www\myFolder`

**actual resul**t in myZip.zip: { - myFolder { index.html, mycss.css, myConn.php} }

**desired result** in myZip.zip:  { index.html, mycss.css, myConn.php}

ps: i tried search options for that but not found.

Comment: Try `C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\*`

Comment: `Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\myZip.zip -Path C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\*` Complete command to achieve this goal - just to avoid questions as to @Tomalak 's fine answer :)

Comment: @Tomek When you know for sure, please write it as an actual answer. My comment was just a guess.

Comment: @Tomalak Ok, thanks:)

Comment: Thanks both for quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your `-Path` being a folder you explicitly include it in the archive.

As already mentioned by [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) giving a wildcard changes that.

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\* -DestinationPath C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\myZip.zip
```

If you supply the parameters in the proper positional order, you don't have to name them:

```
Compress-Archive C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\* C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\myZip.zip
```

To have better control over what is archived you can pipe the source(s) to Compress-Archive
(for example to exclude possible subdirectories)

```
Get-ChildItem C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\* -File | Compress-Archive C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\myZip.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

`Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\myZip.zip -Path C:\wamp64\www\myFolder\*`
 Complete command to achieve this goal